# Closed form of a sequence $1,3,6,10,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find closed form of a sequence $1,3,6,10,...$

What is the easiest method for findind the closed form of this sequence?

Comment: $a_n=a_{n-1}+n$ with $a_0=0$

Comment: @CTNT That's a recursive formula, but not a closed form.

Comment: @mweiss My comment was a hint but I believe the closed form is trivial to obtain.

Comment: If you’re looking for general methods for solving recurrences or even deriving them for a sequence of numbers, Graham, Knuth & Patashnik’s _Concrete Mathematics_ isn’t a bad place to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots (in fact infinitely many) sequences that start out with these four terms, so there is no single, correct answer for this question.

Having said that, the simplest solution by far is to notice that these are the first four [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which are given by $T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.